# Filter SQL query Where clause using OR vs ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, where-clause, coldfusion-2016

I have search form where user selects some criteria before they submit request to the server. This involves search criteria that can be search by `Name`, `Number` or `Show All`. In our existing (old system) previous programmers used something like this:

```
<cfquery name="qryFindRecord" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT RecID, Number, Name
    FROM Dictionary WITH (NOLOCK)       
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND
        <cfswitch expression="#arguments.frm_filterby#">
            <cfcase value="1"><!--- Name --->
                Name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(arguments.frm_search)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" />
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="2"><!--- Number --->
                Number = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2" />
            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase><!--- Show All --->
                1 = 1
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>
    ORDER BY Name
</cfquery>
```

As you see they use `switch` statement to evaluate argument `filter by` and based on that search the query. I was thinking that solution that will involve SQL only will be better in terms of maintenance and efficiency. Here is example:

```
<cfquery name="qryFindRecord" datasource="#dsn#">
    DECLARE @FilterBy INT = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_filterby)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />;

    SELECT RecID, Number, Name
    FROM Dictionary
    WHERE 
        (@FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(arguments.frm_search)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" />)
        OR 
        (@FilterBy = 2 AND Number = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2" />)
    ORDER BY Name
</cfquery>
```

First option (the old way that is used in current system) seems not efficient as one with SQL but I'm not 100% since I do not have deep knowledge about SQL. Second reason is `WITH (NOLOCK)`, I been told by senior programmers that we should use that on every SELECT query in the system. Reading more and doing research seems that is a very bad habit and should not be used. I'm building new system and all what I'm looking for is good practice for this kind of situations that won't cause inefficient system and hard code for the maintenance. If anyone have experience with similar problems please let me know how you handle this. I'm not sure which approach to take and what is the best practice now days.

Comment: `.. WITH (NOLOCK), I been told by senior programmers that we should use that on every SELECT query in the system.`  `Reading more and doing research seems that is a very bad habit and should not be used.` >> You are more correct than they are. They're likely using old info, but `NOLOCK` is probably not really doing what they think it's doing. Plus, it just masks other issues.

Comment: Not an issue in this case, but be careful with short circuiting. It doesn't always work as you'd expect due to the optimizer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/logical-operators-or-and-in-condition-and-order-of-conditions-in-where/

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with MS SQL Server, so YMMV.

`WITH(NOLOCK)` should be decided case-by-case. It makes sense when correctness is less important than performance. It also heavily depends on the kind of operations in your DB.

Regarding your `cfquery`, I think your refactoring is good. Anything that looks closer to a stored procedure has a better chance of being parameterized by the RDBMS, which means efficient execution plan caching. If you can, I would turn it into a stored procedure.

Since this is such a simple query, consider hoisting the conditional logic into ColdFusion and having two queries or stored procedures.

The less dynamic SQL generation you're doing, the less you risk exposing a [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) flaw. I've also found that, after years of debugging ColdFusion applications that use a lot of dynamic SQL, I've developed a twitch whenever I see `1 = 1`... That's usually a sign you should start refactoring.

For instance, to simplify your query further by hoisting the conditional logic out of the query you could say:

```
<cfif arguments.frm_filterby eq 1>
  <cfquery name="qryFindRecord" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT RecID, Number, Name
    FROM Dictionary
    WHERE Name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(arguments.frm_search)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50"/>
    ORDER BY Name
  </cfquery>
<cfelseif arguments.frm_filterby eq 2>
  <cfquery name="qryFindRecord" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT RecID, Number, Name
    FROM Dictionary
    WHERE Number = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2"/>
    ORDER BY Name
  </cfquery>
<cfelse>
  <!--- Invalid request? --->
</cfif>
```

The real difference here being whether you want to read primarily ColdFusion, or SQL.

Or a version which hides more of the DB internals with a [stored procedure](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfstoredproc.html):

```
<cfif arguments.frm_filterby eq 1>
  <cfstoredproc procedure="DictionaryByName" datasource="#dsn#">
    <cfprocparam value="%#trim(arguments.frm_search)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50"/>
    <cfprocresult name="qryFindRecord"/>
  </cfstoredproc>
<cfelseif arguments.frm_filterby eq 2>
  <cfstoredproc procedure="DictionaryByNumber" datasource="#dsn#">
    <cfprocparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2"/>
    <cfprocresult name="qryFindRecord"/>
  </cfstoredproc>
<cfelse>
  <!--- Invalid request? --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Do you mean an example of ColdFusion calling the stored procedure, or the stored procedure itself?

Comment: In general just what would be a good option or way to go. Also that would require example on how to call stored procedure with ColdFusion if that is the solution for this case.

Comment: The "best" implementation depends on a lot of things: the complexity of the query, who is maintaining the query (web or SQL developer), whether the query is complex enough to warrant a stored procedure (temp tables, calling other stored procedures), whether you are performing a transaction... I've added an example of calling a stored procedure.

Comment: For this particular query that I have or something similar that would have two or three more search options is it good fit for stored procedure or not? I know you mentioned few things in your answer but for me as a Web developer it's hard to decide since I'm not sure if that would expose my system and open some security holes.

Comment: Also how that SQL stored procedure would look like?

Comment: `WITH(NOLOCK) should be decided case-by-case. It makes sense **when correctness is less important than performance**.` << This is an important point. Essentially, a `NOLOCK` is the same as `READ UNCOMMITED`, so you could be using data that gets rolled back out of the db. Dirty reads are faster than waiting on another process to complete a transaction, but they are still _dirty reads_. The data you `SELECT` now may not be the same data you `SELECT` in a few seconds. And in my prior CF dev, we'd `SELECT`, then do code stuff, then put the data back. We've possibly polluted our data.

Comment: @Shawn What about SQL stored procedures? I see all kind of proposed solutions but each of them have some draw backs. Is stored procedure way to go/ best way to search database tables? Should I use one single stored procedure with filters in where clause or that better would be if we have multiple  stored procedure?

Comment: @espresso_coffee See Rain's point about who will maintain the sproc? How complex is the query? Will you be joining multiple tables? How large are the tables and how much can be cacheable? I'm usually a big fan of the added layer of abstraction and security that SPROCs can provide, but I'm also not a big fan of developers mucking about in the database unless they know what they are doing and how their queries will affect the overall system. I believe that in most cases the database should do the heavy lifting and the application should just ask for the data. But, as usual, it depends.

Comment: @Shawn I agree with all points that you mentioned. Unfortunately we run everything in our company and I'm in charged of Front/Back-End and DB for this project. For me it's important that search process is efficient and secured. I will be maintaining the code and I designed the database. Stored procedures are something new for me but I definitely want to use them if that would be beneficial for my system.

Comment: Also, just a code review note, I'd add that you are passing in a `cf_sql_varchar` for `Name` and a `cf_sql_char` for `Number`, so make sure those cf datatypes match up to the SQL datatypes so you aren't getting behind-the-scenes implicit conversion of the data. I don't know what type of data is in `Number`, but passing in a `char` type seems off. Something named `Number` and seemingly limited to 2 characters should probably be an integer. But if the database column is actually a `char(2)`, stick with that.

Comment: @espresso_coffee So you manage the database? That will definitely make it easier for you to make the changes you need. Does your query use several tables? How complex is the query? SPROCs can be more secure, and they can help simplify the call from your code. A SQL View might also help, but you can't pass arguments into a View, so you'd have to filter it elsewhere. But it can be more efficient for commonly used query code. Again, depending on how complex your query and data is, a SPROC might be a good way to go. But for a simple query like your above example, I'd probably stick with code.

Comment: The structure of your DB it too broad a topic. We don't even know what RDBMS you're using. The best thing you can do is keep security in mind and profile your application, in that order. When you run into performance issues, consider refactoring your SQL. Rewrite it and test it a number of ways and choose the best one. When you find yourself spending a lot of time in a piece of ColdFusion, refactor that.

Comment: @Rain I believe, from other questions, that it's SQL2008.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - Keep in mind stored procedures aren't a magic bullet. It's just as easy to create an inefficient query with a stored procedure as without. Also, databases like sql server often cache parameterized statements anyway, so there's less overall difference between that and a stored proc than there used to be. Bottom line, you need to profile the queries to gauge performance and efficiency. In terms of security, a good rule is don't use dynamic SQL - either in CF (think `SELECT #column# FROM Table ORDER BY #column#' or inside a stored proc (think EXEC).

Comment: Also, in terms of efficiency LIKE is the one of the *least* efficient operators. Queries that use double wildcards at start and end, LIKE '%something%', usually cause an index scan at best and table scan at worst. When possible, using queries that have a wild card at the end, can be more efficient on indexed columns, LIKE 'startsWith%'.